# ProviderARNs need to be valid Cognito Userpools

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I'm trying to use a list of string inside a sam template but it doesn't work as expected. There is my code

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  Sample SAM Template

Parameters:
  CognitoPoolArns:
    Type: List<String>
    Default: "[\"arn:aws:cognito-idp:eu-west-X:XXXXX:userpool/eu-west-XXXXXXX\",\"arn:aws:cognito-idp:eu-west-X:XXXXXX:userpool/eu-west-XXXXXX\",]"
  

Resources:
 Api:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: dev
      Name: name
      EndpointConfiguration:
        Type: REGIONAL
      Auth:
        DefaultAuthorizer: MyCognitoAuthorizer
        Authorizers:
          MyCognitoAuthorizer:
            UserPoolArn: !Ref CognitoPoolArns
        

  PingGetFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: lambdas/ping_get/
      FunctionName: get-ping
      Handler: main.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.8
      Events:
        API:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref Api
            Path: /api/v1/ping
            Method: get
```

I get this error message : `Errors found during import:         Unable to create authorizer 'MyCognitoAuthorizer': ProviderARNs need to be valid Cognito Userpools. Invalid ARNs- ["arn:aws:cognito-idp:eu- west-X:XXXX:userpool/eu- west-XXXXX" "arn:aws:cognito-idp:eu- west-X:XXXXXX:userpool/eu- west-XXXXX" ]`

But if I do

```
MyCognitoAuthorizer:
                UserPoolArn: 
                       - arn:aws:cognito-idp:eu-west-X:XXX:userpool/eu-west-XXXXXXXX
                       - arn:aws:cognito-idp:eu-west-X:XXX:userpool/eu-west-XXXXXXXX
```

It's working. How can I deal with that by passing by variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the default value of `CognitoPoolArns` parameter in the template as below to resolve the error.

Execute `sam build` command after making the change and then you will be able to deploy successfully.

```
Default: "arn:aws:cognito-idp:eu-west-X:XXXXX:userpool/eu-west-XXXXXXX, arn:aws:cognito-idp:eu-west-X:XXXXXX:userpool/eu-west-XXXXXX"
```